# Lighttpd and OpenCart GET requests with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, lighttpd

Our OpenCart is running on Lighttpd and we use mod_rewrite for SEO.

Whenever we have our rewrite rules on, GET requests such as `http://www.site.com/dev/?gclid=XXX` do not work.

Here are my current rewrite rules for OpenCart:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_rewrite" )

url.rewrite  = (
        "^(.*)--v[^/]*--(.*)$" => "$1$2"
)

url.rewrite-once = ( "^/dev/$" => "/dev/index.php?route=common/home")

url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^/dev/(.*)" => "/dev/index.php?_route_=$1")
```

Which rules I need to add to enable GET requests ?

Comment: Does `/dev/index.php?_route_=?gclid=XXX` exists? Because this is what the last rule does.

Comment: As far as I know, the last rule is required for SEO to work properly